# Unable provide equal heights to all div based on the content using ng-repeat in angularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

I am facing an issue in UI where I am unable to provide equal heights to all the div's which is written based on the ng-repeat in angularJS.

HTML Code:

```
<li role="presentation" ng-show="tariffData.details.tariffDetails.serviceProviderBenefits.length > 0">
    <a href="#networkBenefits" ng-touch="netBenfTab()" ng-click="networkTabHeightTest($index)" aria-controls="collect" role="tab" id="tariffNetworkBenefitsTab" data-event-params="" data-event-name="tariffPageSummaryTab" data-element-channel="ews.tariffFinder" data-event="click" data-toggle="tab">${siteConfigAdapter.config.texts.values['txNetworkBenefits'] @ context='html'}</a></li>

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="networkBenefits">
    <div class="row marginT30">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 paddingB40 paddingB20-xs padBenifit" ng-repeat="networkBenefit in tariffData.details.tariffDetails.serviceProviderBenefits" id="{{$index}}">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 paddingB40 paddingB20-xs">
            <div class="imgDim img {{networkBenefit.cssImageCode}}" ng-show="!placeholderNetworkImage(networkBenefit.cssImageCode)"></div>
            <div class="Ctm_icons tickLightGray" ng-show="placeholderNetworkImage(networkBenefit.cssImageCode)"></div>
            <h4 class="RobotoBcDarkGray30 RobotoBcDarkGray21-xs">{{networkBenefit.networkBenefitName}}</h4>
            <p class="RobotoRDarkGray15 RobotoRGray13-xs">{{networkBenefit.networkBenefitDescription}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$scope.networkTabHeightTest = function () {
    console.log("************networkTabHeightTest() function has been called*****************************");
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $("#networkBenefits .padBenifit").each(function () {
        console.log($(this).height() + "this div height");
        if ($(this).height() >= maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = $(this).height();
            console.log(maxHeight + " max height in if condition");
        } else {
            console.log(maxHeight + " max height in else condition");
        }
    });
    $("#networkBenefits .padBenifit").height(maxHeight);

}
```

[Here's the link to correct working div.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIavE.png)

Screen Shot of the error: [image: Error Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

try using **col-sm-12** instead of **col-sm-6** in below code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 paddingB40 paddingB20-xs padBenifit" ng-repeat="networkBenefit in tariffData.details.tariffDetails.serviceProviderBenefits" id="{{$index}}">
```

Comment: It is hard to help without checking the css